# Como carregar dropdown list usando angularJS e php

Tags: php, angularjs

consegui carregar um drop-down usando o php.
Agora preciso carregar o segundo drop-down, com base na seleção do primeiro.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Valeu.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="statecontroller">
<label>Categorias</label>
<select ng-model="categoria">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option ng-repeat="x in categorias" value="{{ x.id_categoria }}">{{ x.categoria }}</option>
</select>

<label>Subcategorias</label>
<select ng-model="subcategoria">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option ng-repeat="x in subcategorias" value="{{ x.id_subcategoria }}">{{ x.subcategoria }}</option>
</select>
```

```
<script src='js/angular.min.js'></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("statecontroller", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("php/carregaCategorias.php").success(function(response) {
        $scope.categorias=response;
    });
}]);
</script>
```

[image: Primeiro drop-down funcionando]

Comment: Adicione o código.

Comment: Não tenho código @DiegoFelipe

Comment: Gustavo, faça a mesma coisa para a função carregaCategorias.

Comment: Mesmo que esteja funcionando essa parte?

Comment: cara, falei merda. foi mal. não é para mexer. LOL. Qual o estado agora? o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Ta do jeito que está na descrição. Veja acima Cleiton

Comment: E ai pessoal, mais alguma dica?

Comment: Inclui uma solução funcional na minha pergunta, segue também um link para um fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/ybjpvopn/, espero que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Não faça o request usando `$.http` do `jQuery`, ele roda fora do 'ambiente' do angular o que te obriga a atualizar o `$scope`. No seu exemplo, para que funcione, basta que você encapsule a assinatura do valor no método `$apply` do scope.

Segue exemplo:

```
    $.post( urlService, data, function( response ) {
        if ( typeof response.cidades === 'undefined') {
            // Código para tratar erro
        }

        // Receber cidades enviados pelo PHP no formato
        // array( array('id'=>XXX,'nome'=>'yyyy', ...), ...)
        $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.cidades = response.cidades;})
    });
```

Uma solução de exemplo completa segue a baixo:

https://jsfiddle.net/ybjpvopn/

(não publiquei direto aqui no stackoverflow por que ainda está com problemas)

---

Aconselho que, quando você tiver tempo, leia as guidelines da comunidade AngularJS, já que ele ensina algumas regras básicas sobre design de códigicação e regras sobre separação de responsabilidades.

Um importante recurso é o mantido pelo John Papa (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide )

Comment: Veja se é essa mudança que eu fiz no código, aqui do post, que você sugere que eu faça Cleiton.

Comment: Cara, o $http é um service do angular... 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @david, ele alterou a pergunta. Releia minha resposta. Não entendi o -1.

Comment: Tive alguns problemas com o `$http`. Quando fiz consulta entre domínios diferentes, tive que alterar no PHP o header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Também tive problemas com envio de imagens. Não que não pudesse resolver, mas com jquery é mais simples, portanto prefiro.

Comment: @Cleiton agora eu identifiquei, então ao inves de usar o `apply` seria mais correto utilizar o `$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);` pois o angular irá detectar a mudança no escopo e funcionara corretamente.

Comment: E ai pessoal, mais alguma dica?

Comment: Não seria melhor injetar o `API` e usá-lo ao invés do http puro

Answer (score 0):

Código HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body ng-app = 'app'>
        <div ng-controller='MainController'>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="estado">Estado</label>
                <select
                 id         = 'estado'
                 name       = 'estado'
                 ng-model   = 'ufSelecionado'
                 ng-options = '
                    estado.uf                       as
                    estado.uf + " - " + estado.nome for
                    estado                          in
                    estados'
                 ng-change  = 'listarCidades( ufSelecionado )'
                 required
                 >
                    <option value=''>[SELECIONE]</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
                <select
                 id         = 'cidade'
                 name       = 'cidade'
                 ng-model   = 'cidade'
                 ng-options = 'cidade.id as cidade.nome for cidade in cidades'
                 required
                 />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src='[caminho_do_jquery]/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='[caminho_do_angular]/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        // Receber estados do PHP e passar para o javascript
        // como uma array no formato array('uf'=>'nome do estado', ...)
        var estados = <?= json_encode( $estados ) ?>;
    </script>
```

Código Javascript:

```
var dependencias = []; // Declare suas dependências
var App = angular.module( 'App', dependencias );

App.controller( 'MainController', function( $scope ) {

    // Integrar no AngularJs os estados do javascript
    $scope.estados  = estados;
    $scope.cidades  = null;

    // Função para carregar as cidades
    $scope.listarCidades = function( uf ) {
        var urlService  = '...'; // Digite a URL do serviço
        var data        = {
            uf          : uf,
        };

        $.post( urlService, data, function( response ) {
            if ( typeof response.cidades === 'undefined') {
                // Código para tratar erro
            }

            // Receber cidades enviados pelo PHP no formato
            // array( array('id'=>XXX,'nome'=>'yyyy', ...), ...)
            $scope.cidades = response.cidades;
        })
        .error( function() {
            // Código para tratar erro
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Vou tentar @MarcioJalber

Comment: Posso usar JQuery junto com AngularJS?

Comment: To conseguindo trazer os dados, mas não estou conseguindo popular no primeiro dropdown.

Comment: Pode utilizar jquery e angular sem problema algum. Mas você deve chamar o jquery primeiro. Inclusive o angular encapsula algumas funções básicas do jQuery através da sintaxe `angular.element( '#element' )...`.

Comment: @GustavoSevero, me mostre seu código para que eu possa avaliar e apontar onde pode estar o problema.

Comment: Ta semelhante ao seu.

Comment: Percebi um erro e alterei a resposta: na definição de data, estava passando `$scope.uf`, quando era para passar o uf recebido como parâmetro da function. Por favor, altere e me fale se deu certo.

Comment: Ta igual, não mudou nada. Veja como está meu código, na descrição desse post.
Ele puxa os dados corretamente, mas não está populando o primeiro drop-down.

Comment: @GustavoSevero, observe que na definição da variável `data`que é enviada para <strong>php/carregaSubcategorias.php</strong>, você deve alterar de `uf : $scope.uf,` para `uf : uf`.

Comment: @GustavoSevero, outra coisa. Acrescente depois da linha `$scope.subcategorias = response.subcategorias;` a instrução `$scope.$digest();`, para que o angular atualize as informações na view, visto que foram recebidas assincronicamente.

Comment: Fiz as modificações Marcio Jalber, mas continua na mesma.

Comment: Dá um `console.log( response );` para ver o que está retornando do seu serviço `php/carregaSubcategorias.php`.

Comment: Nada, não apareceu nada.

Comment: Acredito que não vai funcionar, pois o primeiro drop-down não está sendo carregado, entende? Os dados da chama do php vem, mas não estão populando o drop-down, entende? Como mostro na imagem que postei aqui.

Comment: E ai pessoal, mais alguma dica?